# Is iWork for free for Yosemite Users?

Tags: iwork, macos

I just upgraded to OS X Yosemite and as far as I recall the presentation Apple said that iWork is for free now as well? The reason I ask is because there is still a price in the App Store.

Or is just the update for owners free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes & No.

It's free for recent Apple hardware purchasers - though irritatingly I can get it for free on my iPhone but not my Mac...

However...
You can download the iWork 09 trial for free & App Store will then update it to the current version.

I'm not sure whether it's strictly legal or not, but I'm sure they could have shut it down years ago if they really didn't like it.

See [How do I convert old Pages documents to Pages '13?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150771/how-do-i-convert-old-pages-documents-to-pages-13/150776#150776)

*Extract :*

Go to [Softpedia](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Business/Apple-iWork-06.shtml#download)

Click on External Mirror 1

This will download iWork09Trial.

Open the dmg & run the installer.

Run any of the 3 apps, then check App Store for updates.

***Edit : After the release of Yosemite, you can no longer update to the latest versions of these if you are still on Mavericks or below. They are now considered "Incompatible Updates". Same for Aperture, iMovie & iPhoto***

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I am not a recent hardware purchaser. It was a nice try. But I get that this item has either been purchased by a different user or refunded. It would have been just too good.

Comment: It works fine for me - just did it again to test.

Comment: Did you buy iWork with your Apple ID at some point? Because I have never bought it. Only on the iPad I get it for free because of a hardware purchase.

Comment: I got the components, Pages, etc for my iPhone for free - my desktop version came via the above route.

Comment: Same trick works for Aperture.

Comment: But if you have done this "thing" while you are still on Mavericks, these apps become a part of your purchase history in App Store. You can download, update, download onto another machine all you want.