# Re-download OS X iWork suite (Pages, Numbers, Keynote)

Tags: imac, pages, iwork, macos

Apple introduced Pages, Numbers, and Keynote as a Mac native platform for documents such as letters, spreadsheets, and presentations. These applications come pre-loaded with OS X, as they did with my computer, however, after re-installing OS X after having unrelated issues with my computer, I found that these iWork applications were simply no longer there. So, I transferred the suite from a colleague's computer to my own, however, said applications soon became obsolete, as I couldn't update them without my colleague's password. So, I deleted the applications once more, as they were rendered useless.

This wasn't too much of a problem until recently, as I began to need the applications for other projects. Whenever I visit the Mac App Store, I'm not able to simply download them, rather, I have to pay money for them. Which, eventually I succumbed to, grudgingly paying the $15 for Pages, but it didn't download. I lost the $15, with no result from the App Store. Pages doesn't show up in the Purchased section of the Store, and there's nothing in my Applications folder that would suggest that it did indeed download.

Any suggestions? Or does this warrant a visit to the Genius Bar?

Specs: iMac 27" Late 2013 running OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Comment: Are you positive you are signed in with the same AppleID that you used to download iWork?

Comment: I don't know whether this route works any more, but worth testing. See my answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150974/is-iwork-for-free-for-yosemite-users/150977#150977

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Do you mean the initial download of the applications when I first turned on the computer, or when I bought Pages off of the App Store? The answers to those are no and yes, in that order.

Comment: Try signing in with the AppleID you used to initially download the apps when you first bought the Mac. @angelplayer

Comment: I'll try it @ComputerScienceStudent

Answer (score 1):

When you bought your Mac, you were prompted to "accept" the applications in the iWork suite, to be attached to your Apple ID for future download.

If you did not do this, I suggest calling Apple Support or taking a trip to the Genius Bar. If you provide them your Mac's proof of purchase, they should be able to give you a redeem code for the App Store to download the suite. This will also link the apps to your Apple ID signed in on the Mac App Store for future download.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you!