# Copy contents of Numbers file on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, numbers

When I ran OS X Yosemite, I worked on a *.numbers* file. Just recently, I needed to acces the contents of that file. However, the file opens only in Preview, and the Numbers app appears to be a paid one. I don't remember Numbers being a paid app in the last release of OS X.

How can I open that file without paying for the Numbers app? I really just need to copy the contents?

Comment: Numbers, Pages & Keynote are all free with a qualifying Apple purchase. There was a break-point when iWork was discontinued, though certainly for a time, you could install iWork & it would auto-update. idk whether that is still true. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150977/85275

Comment: If I understood correctly, because I have 2 years old MBP I must pay for Numbers.

Comment: I have a 2013 Air and I'm able to download Numbers for free from the App Store.  You don't mention in your question if you've tried to download Numbers from the MAS.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is MAS?

Comment: The machine should have qualified when it was new, assuming you are using the same Apple ID for the machine as for App Store

Comment: @sanjihan, MAS is Mac App Store. Although the app's name is just App Store, not Mac App Store.